# Fuse link system for LED bulbs?

Tags: led, light, led-strip

I recently learned how incandescent Christmas bulbs can be modified to continue conducting electricity after burning out thanks to a fuse link that bridges the two leads at the base of the bulb.

> When the filament burns out and stops conducting, the entire circuit voltage is briefly across the fuse link.  This voltage is greater than the breakdown voltage of the insulator on the fuse link, which causes the insulation to break down and turns the fuse link into the new direct path.

[image: image of bulb with fuse link]

I was curious about how something similar could be accomplished with LED bulbs.  If it would use the same system, where in the LED would the fuse be placed?

Side note: I'm new.  If my terminology is wrong, please let me know so I can do better research in the future!

Comment: No a thermal relay or fused bridge link is not possible

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Is there an alternative system that would create a similar result?  Is there any way to set up LEDs in series in a way that would allow them to continue working if one breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such a protection device exists for LEDs.  It's based on a circuit that triggers an SCR when there's more than normal LED forward voltage across it:

[LED shunt protector](http://www.bourns.com/products/circuit-protection/led-shunt-protectors-lsps)